# Angular. FromEvent with component reference of itself

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to take adventage of RxJS and FromEvent to capture scroll event like this:

```
fromEvent(componentReference, 'scroll').
pipe(
 takeUntil(this.destroy$),
 tap(() => doSomething()))
.subscribe();
```

I need to listen to scroll event of the component container.
I know I can get reference of the component like this:

```
private readonly comRef = inject(ElementRef);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the scroll event is triggered on your component, not on the whole window. you can do this by following this in your component CSS file

```
:host {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Also define `fromEvent` in `ngAfterViewInit()` hook

```
export class ComponentA implements AfterViewInit {

  public constructor(private comRef: ElementRef){}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent(this.comRef.nativeElement, 'scroll')
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      tap(() => console.log('scrolling'))
    )
    .subscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I completly forgot to refer to native element.